# how do I cut an image into a cube?

Tags: 3d-printing

[image] [image]how do engrave this image of a shogi game board onto the face of the cube, for context this is for a model I'm planning on 3d printing (just incase that changes anything)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please provide at least a sketch of what you'd like to do, unclear what you mean by "cut an image into a cube", billions of options IMHO. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information about your actual goal.

Comment: You could do it with some extrusions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the *displace modifier* to your cube, and click the *New* button.

Then click on this button:
[image]

This will take you to the Textures Tab.

There, click *Open* and then select your image.

Now, go to the *Edit Mode* and subdivide your cube many times.

Then, select all the vertices of the face of the cube where you want the image to be, something like this:
[image]

Now, go to the *Object Data Properties* tab and click the *+* option in *Vertex Groups*:
[image]

Now, click on the *Assign* button.

Go back to the *Modifiers* tab and then click on the box next to the *Vertex Group* and select *Group*.

After going back to the *Object Mode*, the image will appear on the face of the cube.

Note that you can change the height of the image by changing the value of *Strength* in the modifier properties.

My example:

Image:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: thx for all the help mate i had some issues with getting the right amount of sub divides that would let me get all the cubes and numbers looking good but not have blender crash>.< also my cube now has rounded corners so that's a pretty nice edition lol. Have a good one

Comment: You are welcome! :)